# Regex match beginning of string and capture last part

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following set of strings

```
big-div button-green
big-div button-red
big-div button-yellow
```

and I'd like to get the following result

```
green
red
yellow
```

I managed to get this far `/\sbutton-[^\s]*/gi` but matches the whole string as in `button-yellow`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a capturing group around `[^\s]*` and you can access that as the first capturing group.

Alternatively, I'd write that as...

```
var match = (str.match(/\sbutton-(\S*)/gi) || [])[1];
```

This will give you the match, or `undefined` if it couldn't match anything.

If `str` is a class too, I'd swap the boundaries  for `(?:^|\s)` and `(?:$|\s)` or otherwise match on `\s` and wrap the matching string with spaces.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your prompt reply. Your solution works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/\sbutton-([^\s]*)/i)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the title: just create a capture group:

```
/\sbutton([^\s]+)$/i
```

and get the first element of the returned matches array, that'll contain only those chars you're interested in

Comment: That would also match `big-button-green`, which may be contrary to what the OP wants.